# How to use preprocessor directives in packages or references

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I created 3 projects in my C# application solution:

1. Server Side Project
2. Client Side Project
3. Shared Between Server and Client Project (like models)

Server side project has many models used entity framework for Data Base, and client side does not need Database but models are shared between client side and server side because I don't want to make duplicated models in server and client.

Now my client side project uses shared project but does not need EF package(shared project used EF package). I can use "Preprocessor Directives" to prevent build context and attributes (like Index and Key and ...) for client side I cannot prevent EF package in shared project because client side and server side projects uses shared project and shared project has database models and I want to use Preprocessor Directives for prevent EF package for client side but server side must use EF package in shared project.

Have you any idea or any way for my question?

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: i cannot write any code for use preprocessor directives on visual studio packages.that is my question, how can i do this.